# Prevent footer from overlapping

Tags: css, html, overlap

I have read numerous posts here regarding this same issue, however I couldn't find
a relevant solution to my problem....

My current resolution is `1440x900` and the site behaves well, meaning that the footer stops right below my menuwrap.

When I change resolution, the footer overlaps it when I scroll all the way down.

Thanks in advance!

My HTML is:

```
    <body>
            <div id="mainwrap">
                <div id ="menuwrap">
                    <a href="index.html"><div id="menulogo"></div></a>
                </div>

                <div id="mainarea_wrap">
                                 (A LOT OF TEXT-- like 30 lines or so)
                </div>

                <div id="footer">

                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
```

My CSS is:

```
body{
padding:0;
margin:0;
background:url(bg.gif);
background-attachment:fixed;
font-family: Verdana, Arial;
font-size: 0.8em;
}

#mainwrap{
margin-top:30px;
width:800px; 
height:600px; 
position:relative; 
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

#mainarea_wrap{
width:600px;
height:auto;
position:relative;
left:201px;
text-align:justify;
padding:20px;
margin-bottom:-1px;
border-top:solid 1px;
border-right:solid 1px;
border-bottom:solid 1px;
border-color:#D8D8D8;
border-left:solid gray 1px;
border-top-right-radius:10px 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius:10px 10px;
background-color:#F0F0F0;
}

#menuwrap{
height:549px;
width:200px;
position:fixed;
padding-top:20px;
padding-left:20px;
background-color:white;
border:solid 1px;
border-color:#D8D8D8;
border-top-left-radius:10px 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius:10px 10px;
}

#menulogo{
width:200px;
height:150px;
position:relative;
background:url(jmedicas.png) no-repeat;
margin-top:-13px;
margin-left:-20px;
}

#footer{
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:25%;
border:solid 1px;
border-bottom:none;
border-color:#D8D8D8;
padding:20px;
padding-top:0px;
background: #ffffff; /* old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%); /* firefox */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#e5e5e5)); /* webkit */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e5e5e5',GradientType=0 ); /* ie */
border-top-right-radius:10px 10px;
border-top-left-radius:10px 10px;
}

.shadow {
-moz-box-shadow: -5px 4px 8px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: -5px 4px 8px #000;
box-shadow: -5px 4px 8px #000;
/* For IE 8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000')";
/* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000');
}
```

Comment: What resolution are you changing to that "breaks it"?

Comment: every resolution below the one i'm using. If I go to a higher one, the footer just does'nt reach the menu bar (my goal is for the footer to stop right below the menubar, while still being able to see the bottom of the footer/page

Comment: Am I missing something here? Can you not just add a `margin-top` directive to your footer to prevent any overlap?

Comment: I've tried that... but it won't work.. as soon as I change resolution, the footer overlaps the menuwrap when i scroll down the page

Answer (score 2):

I noticed a few things that were breaking your layout.

One was the total width of your elements. You had the widths set to fit within your `#mainwrap`, but also had set padding on them. The padding was being added to the total width of the elements, so your `#mainarea_wrap` instead of being 600px, was actually 640px wide (+20px of padding on each side). Since the wrapper width of 800px was exceeded by your two elements, it broke the layout.

Another was the relative positioning you were using to move your elements around. I think a more effective way to position your elements would be with floats. If you float the `#menuwrap` to the left, and your `#mainarea_wrap` to the right with the corrected widths, they will sit nicely in your `#mainwrap`.

If you use this technique you can use `clear:both;` on your `#footer` to make sure it will always show up beneath those two elements.

**Here's a stripped down jsfiddle showing what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/9XWAL/**

(Ignore the garish colors! I just set them quickly for visual reference).

Hopefully that helps! Good luck!

Comment: I need my #Mainwrap to be fixed so that I can scroll the content while the menu bar is always there... I'll try using floats though.

Comment: I've successfully implemented the sticky footer. Although it's not a bad sollution, I would like the footer to scroll down as well...

Comment: In that case, you may need to give the `#mainarea_wrap` some margin-lovin, like: `margin-left: 200px`, still keeping `float: right` to keep it from overlapping the #menuwrap

Comment: Doesn't work when unzooming. So it's just an element like any other.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've got this settled or not, but here's how I solved a similar problem.

My footer kept overlapping my content. The basic structure is as follows:

```
body
div id=page_container
div id=bodywrap
content
/div
/div
div id=footer
/div
```

It looked great maximized, but when I shrunk the window (or hit the developer tools) the bottom would overlap to the size of the footer.

So I stuck a div called footpad at the end of the page container, after the bodywrap

```
body
div id=page_container
div id=bodywrap
content
/div
div id=footpad
/div
/div
div id=footer
/div
```

and modified the css as follows:

```
28 #page_container {
29         position:relative;
30         width:960px;
31         background-color:#ffffff;
32         margin:0 auto;
33         text-align:left;
34         height:auto !important;
35         height:100%;
36         min-height:100%;
37 }

97 #footer {
98         background-color: #DFE1E1;
99         color:#949595;
100         position:relative;
101         margin-top:-151px;
102         padding:15px;
103         width:100%;
104         clear:both;
105 }

151 #footpad {
152         width:100%;
153         height:151px;
154         position:relative;
155 }
```

And now it works beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

The space you have provided underneath the logo is smaller than the height of the footer so the footer has to overlap the logo when scrolled. The reason it works on some resolutions is because the height of 25% varies. Instead what you need is a fixed height on the footer like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/rVNcX/)

Comment: I tried that, but the footer sticks to the bottom of the page.. I want the footer to show up when you reach the bottom, but prevent it from overlapping the #menuwrap

Comment: You could try moving the markup for your footer outside of the `#mainwrap`? Like the stickyfooter [example](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html). Don't know if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: but the footer doesnt overlap the logo.. it only overlaps the menuwrap.. i'ltt try working with margins.. like Nathan said

Comment: Sorry thats what i meant. theres not enough room under the menu wrap for the footer to fit

Comment: as far as the side scolling goes... i'll just use overflow-x:hidden... since the page is 800x600 I dont need anyone scrolling sideways LOL.... one thing i nnoticed though, is that, when i change resolution, the footer takes up a larger portion of the screen, and so does my #menuwrap, in order for them not to overlap, my footer would have to be drastically resized so that the #menuwrap and footer are totally displayed in my page... I didn't explain that very well... but i'm also not english or american -.-"

Comment: @Luke, yes... you're right.. depending on the resolution there will be more or less space below the #menuwrap... :S

Comment: well... it seems like (and it's a bit obvious) that the problem is also raised when I resize my window.... since the footer is always at the bottom of the page, and my menubar is fixed, the footer will, again, overlap my menubar... i'm trying to work with margins to see what i can do