# Making a Footer stay at the bottom and not overlap on zoom with dynamically generated height main content - Sticky footer doesn't work

Tags: css, html, footer

I am working on a large website for a client and we have run into an issue with the previous designers structure.  The footer does not stay at the bottom of the content when it is dynamically generated.  I have hidden divs that are opened with links.  These divs contain user comments.  When both are opened the footer overlaps some of the content.  When I zoom in the footer overlaps some of the main content.  I've tried:

Ryan Fait's CSS and HTML5 Sticky Footers 
[How to keep footer at the bottom even with dynamic height website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815784/how-to-keep-footer-at-the-bottom-even-with-dynamic-height-website) 
CSS Reset Sticky Footer 
[Prevent footer from overlapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391955/prevent-footer-from-overlapping)

All with no success.  Is doing a full restructure the only option?  I've also tried using JavaScript to make the footer stay at the bottom of the content.  But once the document is loaded and the height changes, the footer doesn't move with content.  Ideas?  The code I have is very long - 4000 lines of css, 2000 lines of HTML.  Should I post part?

Comment: If you can narrow down the code to just the components that recreate the issue, posting it here (and maybe in http://jsfiddle.net/ too) would be helpful for us. Other resources, like images displaying the problem, also better equip us to help you. If you really feel there's not much else you can do, you could post a link to the site exhibiting the problem...but only use that as a last resort, since this question would lose its potential value to the community should the link break in the future.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out @Cat Amber?